# Weird output in using seq(), giving scientific notation and incorrect values

Tags: r

I'm trying to do something very simple: print a sequence of numbers using the seq() function. I entered the following:
    `seq(-.3, 1.2, .1)`

Rather than 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, etc.... I get the following:
    `[1] -3.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01  5.551115e-17  1.000000e-01  2.000000e-01  3.000000e-01  4.000000e-01  5.000000e-01
[10]  6.000000e-01  7.000000e-01  8.000000e-01  9.000000e-01  1.000000e+00  1.100000e+00  1.200000e+00`

Why is it giving me results in scientific notation? And why does it print 0.0 as 5.551115e-17? 5.551115e-17 does not equal 0.0, although it is close. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try with `options(scipen = 999)`

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/324364

Comment: `options(scipen = 999)` did not help, but it did show that apparently all numbers in my output are approximations rather than the values I wish to obtain.

Comment: floating point errors... this is not R, it is computer!

Comment: use integers to prevent floating point errors.. `seq( -3, 12, 1) / 10` will get you the desired result..

Comment: Good idea Wimpel! Thanks!